# Know when user's screen turns off/on

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I want to execute some background data saving when the user's screen turns off, and stop it when the user's screen turns back on.

How can I do that ?

registering a broadcast receiver for the following actions

android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT
android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF

but the receiver does not get called....

```
   <receiver
            android:name="com.myapp.receivers.Receiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

It is only called for "boot completed"

I am using the following permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: I did that, as i said, it is not called for anything other than boot completed

Comment: Try removing this: `android:exported="false"`

Comment: if you want to do background task when you are on particular activity, you can do it on onResume() (screen on) and onPause (screen off)

Comment: @RipalTamboli my app my not be running at this point...